# Flutter Dismissable widget onDismissed doesn't fire

Tags: flutter, landscape, mobile-development

I have 3 section, one is ClassList widget which contains Dismissible widgets. ClassList has the _refreshGPA function parameter which is called the setState() method for rebuild the screen. So, when onDismissed fired, _refreshGPA method called by the ClassList widget and list item removed correctly. Every thing is working.

```
body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      _buildClassForm(context),
      GPAHeader(gpa: gpa),
      ClassList(_classList, _refreshGPA),
    ],
  ),
```

So, I try to make a layout for lanscape mode by using OrientationBuilder. I implement two method for each layout mode. But now, list items doesn't removed in both layout mode.

```
body: OrientationBuilder(
    builder: (context, orientation) {
      if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
        return _bodyPortraitMode(context);
      } else {
        return _bodyLandscapeMode(context);
      }
    },
  ),

Widget _bodyPortraitMode(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      _buildClassForm(context),
      GPAHeader(gpa: gpa),
      ClassList(_classList, _refreshGPA),
    ],
  ),
);

Widget _bodyLandscapeMode(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: _buildClassForm(context),
        flex: 1,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            GPAHeader(gpa: gpa),
            ClassList(_classList, _refreshGPA),
          ],
        ),
        flex: 1,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

I tryed theese two method alone by passing to body, and working fine. But when wraped by OrientationBuilder list item doesn't removed.

Thank you for any helping!
And sorry my spelling mistake, eng. doesn't my main lanuage.

Comment: On a side note, you should really avoid using functions as it's a very bad practice. Use `StatelessWidget` instead with a constant constructor, it can drastically improve your app's performance (the subtree is cached)

Comment: The difference between `return _bodyPortraitMode(...)` and `return const BodyPortraitMode()` can be very important in terms of performances! Give a look at the official documentation about `StatelessWidget`

Answer (score 0):

Based on this page https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48290, I generate Scaffold widgets for each layout mode and then return in if-else block.
I hope it helps someone.